# Weaker condition than split exactness that also gives an exact sequence after tensoring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Fix $A$-modules $M, N, L, K$. Suppose $K$ is not flat. Suppose $0\to M\to N \to L \to 0$ is an exact sequence.

If $0\to M\to N \to L \to 0$ splits, then we have an exact sequence
$$
0\to M \otimes K\to N \otimes K \to L \otimes K \to 0.
$$

Is there a weaker condition on $0\to M\to N \to L \to 0$ than split exactness, such that $0\to M \otimes K\to N \otimes K \to L \otimes K \to 0$ is exact?

Comment: Are you fixing $M,N,L,K$ or are they varying?

Comment: @Mohan I have them fixed.

Comment: The only conditions I can see is $\operatorname{Tor}^A_1(L,K)=0$, or the exact sequence is a pure exact sequence (i.e. a direct limit of split exact sequences).